# I can not create a folder drawable-xxxhdpi

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I created a folder drawable-xxxhdpi  in my project in android studio. But android studio does not see this folder. how do I create this folder right?

Comment: I thought about the problem. created it again and earned. Do not know what the problem was

Answer (score 3):

folders are not visible, when empty, if you are in the *Android* perspective. Switch to the *Packages*, perspective and it should be visible
. You should be able to switch perspectivies in the drop down menu on the top-left

Comment: I created it. I put her in the picture. it is not empty. but the android: src = "@ drawable / plus" does not see it